# sun.misc.unsafe causes ClassNotFoundException in older Android-api - 17

Tags: java, android

I am using lmax disruptor which is referring to class Unsafe ( sun.misc.unsafe package)

> https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lmax/disruptor/util/Util.java

This works in api above 17 but giving ClassNotFoundException in Android - api 15,16,17 etc

Which is not letting me give support for my App for older versions.

how could i load this class manually or provide this in a jar so that class loader finds this class

Comment: You shouldn't be using it at all. See [
Why Developers Should Not Write Programs
That Call 'sun' Packages
](http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/faq-sun-packages.html).

Comment: well yes...but how did newer version of android works but not the older versions...can i use alternate class , i can then raise a PR on github on LMAX disruptor